# Time complexity of sorting a list in descending order.

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I have a list of pair of variables along with their correlation value stored in a database.

```
var1  var2  corr
```

My algorithm involves sorting the list in descending order (based on correlation values) and then retrieving top k pairs.

What would be the time complexity of this algorithm? Does it depend on how I am sorting it? I am sorting the list with sql query using ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Which SQL platform are you using?  Do you have an index defined on `corr`

Comment: The answer to that question will be implementation specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683180/time-complexity-of-sorting-a-database

Comment: @Hogan I am using SQL Server 2010, and I don't have an index in the table.

Comment: @SaadH - Still depends on the platform, but probably O(log N).  Test it.

Comment: @Hogan , if sorting would have been implemented using a programming language, complexity would have been still the same i.e. O(log N) ?

Comment: @SaadH - I'm not sure what you are asking SaaH. The size of your data set will also have a big impact.  Are you sorting millions or rows or thousands?  If you add an index you should see a big difference if you have a lot of rows an index should speed up the sorting to O(1) but on a small dataset you will have other things that are slower (eg network transfer).

Comment: @Hogan , I am sorting millions of rows. So what I understand is, time complexity depends on not just 1 factor but a combination of factors. My goal is to calculate the time complexity for the algorithm I am using, but my understanding now is there are other factors involved, and time complexity cannot be calculated from the algorithm alone.

Comment: @SaadH - That is a nice goal.  Do you have a question.  I'm not clear on what exactly you are asking here.

Comment: @Hogan , question is what would be the complexity of the sorting algorithm? You have already answered that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL databases manage multiple-level memory -- basically data pages in memory and storage on disk. Traditional measures of complexity do not do a good job of capturing performance characteristics of SQL queries.  For that, you need to understand the execution plan, underlying algorithms, and size of data relative to available resources.

My next reaction is: If you need to sort the data, then sort the data.  What does time complexity have to do with it? That is, what other options do you have?

In general, the sorts implemented in databases are going to have O(n log(n)) complexity. However, the actual speed depends heavily on other factors. An index on the column reduces the complexity. Data that fits in memory goes faster. Data that fits on a single page is likely to be faster yet.

I am not sure what you mean by "Does it depend on how I am sorting it?". There is only one way to express ordering in SQL, using the `order by` clause, and it doesn't have many options. Ordering by `asc` versus `desc` should have no or minimal impact on performance.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment. What I meant by that sentence was, does the time complexity change if the algorithm is implemented using a programming language instead of SQL.

Comment: Still don't understand the question.  "Sorting" is a task.  There are many algorithms for it.  If you implement the same algorithm(s) used in the database, they will have the same complexity.

Comment: So a sort without an index would have a complexity of O(n*logn) ? or we cannot say it for sure without other factors that you have mentioned?

Comment: @SaadH . . . It is implementation-specific.  Just most reasonable sorting algorithms are O(n*logn).  There is no reason to think that database developers would be unreasonable.